# Moodle SQL - tabela de registro respostas de um questionário por aluno

Tags: moodle

Faaaaala galera!
No moodle, no banco de dados, em uma atividade quiz, onde encontro a tabela de registro de respostas dadas por alunos em um determinado questionário?

Eu estou fazendo assim, onde no campo lastname, é onde coloco um código para escola e no campo institution uso para colocar nome da escola, está correto o raciocínio lógico? rsrs:

```
SELECT 
     SUBSTRING(u.`department`,2,5) AS Turma,
     u.`firstname` AS Aluno,
     u.`lastname` AS Siem,
     u.`institution` AS Escola,
     i.`itemname` AS Simulado,
     g.`finalgrade` AS Nota, 

(select count(u.`firstname`) 

from  `mdl_grade_items` i INNER JOIN `mdl_grade_grades` g ON i.`id` = g.`itemid` INNER JOIN `mdl_user` u ON g.`userid` = u.`id`

  where itemid = 6  and courseid = 2  and lastname = 213 AND finalgrade != "NULL") totalAlunos,

(select avg(finalgrade) 

from  `mdl_grade_items` i INNER JOIN `mdl_grade_grades` g ON i.`id` = g.`itemid` INNER JOIN `mdl_user` u ON g.`userid` = u.`id`

  where itemid = 6  and courseid = 2  and lastname = 213 and department = ".5anoA") notaTurmaA,

(select avg(finalgrade) 

from  `mdl_grade_items` i INNER JOIN `mdl_grade_grades` g ON i.`id` = g.`itemid` INNER JOIN `mdl_user` u ON g.`userid` = u.`id`

  where itemid = 6  and courseid = 2  and lastname = 213 and department = ".5anoB") notaTurmaB,

(select avg(finalgrade)

from  `mdl_grade_items` i INNER JOIN `mdl_grade_grades` g ON i.`id` = g.`itemid` INNER JOIN `mdl_user` u ON g.`userid` = u.`id`

  where itemid = 6  and courseid = 2  and lastname = 213) as NotaGeralEscola

FROM
     `mdl_grade_items` i INNER JOIN `mdl_grade_grades` g ON i.`id` = g.`itemid`
     INNER JOIN `mdl_user` u ON g.`userid` = u.`id`

WHERE
     i.courseid = 2  AND itemtype = "mod"  AND itemmodule = "quiz"  AND finalgrade != "NULL"  AND g.`itemid` = 6


ORDER BY
     u.`department` ASC, finalgrade desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você consegue algo, com uma consulta similar a esta, adapte ela de acordo com o que você precisa:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.id, q.name, q.questiontext,  qw.id, qw.answer,qa.id, qa.rightanswer as resposta_aluno
FROM mdl_quiz_attempts qt 
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qt.uniqueid=qa.questionusageid 
INNER JOIN mdl_question_answers qw ON qa.questionid=qw.question
INNER JOIN mdl_question q on q.id = qa.questionid
WHERE qt.id=? // ID DA TENTATIVA, NA TABELA quiz_attempts
ORDER BY qw.id ASC;
```